# How do I compute the expectation value of a product of of random variable, pulled from separate distributions, but those distributions are correlated?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, multinomial-distribution

I want to compute the following expectation value:$$\langle \phi_i ~m_j \rangle$$
Where $\phi_i \sim \text{multinomial}(s_1,(p_1,...,p_N))$ and $m_j\sim\text{multinomial}(s_2,(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_N))$

That is to say that $\phi_i$ is drawn from a multinomial distribution that draws $N$ different colored balls each with probability $p_a$ from a bag of $s_1$ balls. (The probability of drawing type $i$ is $p_i$) Meanwhile $m_j$ is drawn from a multinomial distribution that draws $N$ different numbered balls each with probability $\alpha_a$ from a bag of $s_2$ balls. (The probability of drawing type $j$ is $\alpha_j$)

Now on the surface this problem is easy, $\phi_i$ and $m_j$ appear uncorrelated and thus we can simply say that $$\langle \phi_i~m_j\rangle=\langle\phi_i\rangle\langle m_j\rangle$$

However, $s_1$ and $s_2$ are both random variables drawn from the same distribution specifically $$s_1,s_2\sim \text{multinomial}(T,(S_1,S_2,...,S_M))$$

If we assume that this isn't an issue then we can just say that
$$\langle \phi_i~m_j\rangle=\langle\phi_i\rangle\langle m_j\rangle=p_i\langle s_1\rangle\alpha_j\langle s_2\rangle=p_i\alpha_j S_1 S_2 T^2$$

But I'm not sure that this is okay to do. Does the fact that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are drawn from separate distribution that are themselves determined by correlated variables change anything? If so, how?

Comment: The issue is whether $s_1$ and $s_2$ are independent samples from the same distribution or whether they are distinct elements of the same single sample (and so presumably negatively correlated here)

Comment: So I think that they are distinct elements from the same single sample. If they were independent that would mean that I'm redrawing every time right? I'm not doing that. They are both drawn from the same distribution at the same time. If I were to draw all $(s_1,...,s_M)$ they would sum to $T$.

Comment: So they are negatively correlated, reducing the expectation of their product

Comment: Yes. If I were drawing them separately then their product could be at most $T^2$ in that case where all balls drawn were the same type from each draw. Since they are being drawn from the same box their product can be at most $\left(\frac{T}{2}\right)^2$ in the case where half of the balls were type 1 and half were type 2. How do I indicate this in my notation? How does this change my answer?

Comment: $\langle \phi_i~m_j\rangle = p_i \alpha_j\langle s_1~ s_2\rangle$ would be a start

Comment: Hmm... okay that makes some intuitive sense that that's what I was kind of guessing I should do if I do something differently? But why does this work?

Comment: I do not do chat.  That works by linearity of expectation but you cannot apply it to  $\langle s_1~ s_2\rangle$

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. Sorry about the chat notification. Stack exchange just suggested I do that and clicked the link not understanding what would happen. Thanks for your help!